# setOnLongClickListener and setOnClickListener issue

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I have a listview. What I would like to achieve is that when I longclick any item it will show a dialog menu. However I have a click listener as well. it gets triggered after long click. How Can I cancel that or is there a way of ignoring clcik action for longclick.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Check this out](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener%28android.view.View.OnLongClickListener%29):

There is a specific method for `setOnLongClickListener`. Just make sure that you `setLongClickable` to be true for your `ListView`! You need to separate the listeners you define for a normal click and a long click.

Other than that, try posting some of your code. It will allow the community to better help you.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are setting the click listener directly on each of the views corresponding to the items in the list, probably in the `getView` method of your `ListAdapter` with a code similar to this :

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(final View v)
   {
      // DO SOMETHING
   }
 });
```

If you do this, the `OnClickListeners` on these views override the listener set at the  `ListView` level (with `registerForContextMenu(listView)`) and your context menu will never get called on a long click.

The right way is to set your menu (with long click) and your click listener both at the `ListView` level :

```
registerForContextMenu(listView);
listView.setOnItemClickListener( 
    new OnItemClickListener() {        
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long l) {
            // DO SOMETHING 
            // selected item is a.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    }
    });
```

PS : I'm answering because I had the same issue and I feel the accepted answer with `setOnLongClickListener` is probably not the recommended way to do this if you need a contextual menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this the right way, read up on [Context Menu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html). Otherwise you can do it the easy but messy way using pop-up dialogs and by overriding listview's `onItemLongClickListener`